# Creating a dictionary using data types from user input

Tags: python, arcpy, file-formats, dictionary, directory

To better organize data, I want to create a dictionary that takes a directory path as an argument and groups the items by datatype (for example: u'ShapeFile': ['abc.shp']). However, I run into an issue every time I try to use the describe object (desc) to classify them by dataType:

```
import arcpy, os, sys

inputDir = sys.argv[1]
fileList = os.listdir(inputDir)
fileDict= {}

for f in fileList:
    print f
    desc = arcpy.Describe(f)
    print "Data Type: " + desc.dataType
```

Every time I use this method, it throws an IOError: saying that the first item it tries to use the describe.dataType on doesn't exist.

How do I incorporate the describe function into the code so that it pulls out the dataType?

Comment: Have you configured a tool dialog to sit in front of this code to make it into a Python Script Tool in a standard toolbox?

Comment: Have you tried `print(fileList)` immediately after setting it so that you can see the first item in it?  If so, then what is that first item?

Comment: `hasattr` https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/describe-object-properties.htm but I would use [`arcpy.ListDatasets`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listdatasets.htm) instead of `os.listdir`

Comment: "All data, regardless of the data type, will always acquire the generic Describe properties." (see 
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/describe.htm, https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/describe.htm) That said the property `dataType` should always be present. Could you post the full `IOError`?

Answer (score 5):

In `arcpy.Describe(f)` the variable `f` will evaluate to the filename only, without a directory. arcpy will search for that file in the 'current' directory, i.e. `os.getcwd()`.

You need to either specify the full filename, or make sure the script runs in the correct folder.

Example:

```py
desc = arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(inputDir, f))
```